# UITableVIew controller in completely black color

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have requirement to show **UITableViewController in completely black color**.

I am facing **below problem**:

**I have set background color of cell as black color**. I have only **four entries** so those four `cells` are in black color with White Colored text. But now other empty cells are also displayed and those are in **white colors**.

Comment: Put some code related to your problem....!

Comment: Do you want cell background black or whole table background black ?

Answer (score 5):

Give Your

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

And also give

```
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you does not want to see `separatorStyle` of your `UITableViewCell` then also write following code.

```
self.myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

If you use All Of this code  then you can see your `UITableView` Completely black.

Answer (score 2):

Make the tableView background color as black and make the cell's background Color as clear color. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

just set background color black color of your tableview from xib like

[image]

And make your cell background color clearColor.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra empty cells from the tableview.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

    if ([self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView] == (section+1))
    {

        return [UIView new];

    }

    return nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tableview background color black color.

```
[yourtableview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

and remove cell background color means Clear color , it will work fine for You.